# include a .tex file with spaces in the filename

Tags: latex, include, whitespace

I am including chapters in my latex file one by one by using the `\include{}` statement, up till now I've had no problem with that. But I've recently written a chapter which I've saved under a name including spaces...because you can.

Now the `include{}` statement apparently doesn't like spaces, and prints just the filename in my document in stead of the chapter.

It is probably a pretty easy fix (apart from removing the spaces in the filename, ;-) ), but I can't find it.

**UPDATE**

It doesn't bode well for this question according to this [wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/LaTeX/FilesWithSpecialChars). It says that you can't unless you use a recent distribution like teTeX 3 or MikTeX 2.4.

However one smidge of hope left, the page is dated 2005 (a lot can happen in 5 years) and I am using pdflatex included in ubuntu which I assume is a fairly recent distribution.

Comment: unfortunately, the latex distribution, the last time I checked, in the repos for ubuntu is texlive2007. which is a bit outdated. TL2009 is quite nice, includes a packagemanager and a host of other nice things for your tex-ing needs.

Comment: When using a flat file, (just using a .txt file), you can also use `\input{"./Chapters/My Chapter Name.txt"}`.  Although there is a TeX community at stack, it is still considered programming, (like XSL, etc.).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I'm closing this question by giving the (quite unsatisfying) answer, I've found (on this [wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/LaTeX/FilesWithSpecialChars)).

At the moment the answer unfortunately is: you can't, unless you use a recent version which happens to handle this problem more gracefully. Examples: [teTeX](http://web.bilkent.edu.tr/History/valley/tetex-index.html) 3 and [MikTeX](http://www.miktex.org/) 2.4.

It seems that unusual filenames are still a problem within latex, so your best bet is to abstain or, if you have to, find a version that has solved the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
\include{"file\space name"}
```

(I.e., use quotes and `\space`.)  You may need to remove old `.aux` files and/or run Latex twice.

Comment: It doesn't work I'm afraid. It goes through the .tex fine with this solution, but hangs on the .aux now.

Comment: I believe this works on images only.

Comment: @NomeN: I tried it and it worked for my simple test case, but I am not sure if it's supposed to work with everything.

Answer (score 7):

It works. What you need to do is if your chapter file is `File Of Mine.tex` then in the main .tex file put

```
\include{"File\space Of\space Mine"}
```

but inside `File Of Mine.tex` you just need to have `\chapter{File Of Mine}`. Try this and see if it works for you. It does for me.

Comment: Whether there's a `\chapter` command shouldn't change whether this works or not.  Will it "work" a second time? @NomeN says using the `\space` macro in the file name will allow the `.tex` file to be loaded, but not the corresponding `.aux` file.